# Importing contacts from Windows Phone 10

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9, device-migration

Trying to set up my new Galaxy S9+ today and I'm moving from a Lumia 950XL running Windows 10 Mobile - and for the life of me I can't get it to import my contacts.

The obvious solution would appear to be the Smart Switch app, however: I installed it on both devices, set the S9 to "receive" and connected the 950 to the Wifi network SS created, unfortunately it just sits on "Connecting.." on the 950-side (despite the S9 side claiming it's connected).

Other things I've tried:

- Adding my One Drive account - Nope, no option to sync the contacts.
- "Linking" the S9 to my Win10 laptop via Link My Phone - Nope, it shows as linked, shows up in my Microsoft Account when I log in there but no apparent way to sync anything.
- Adding Microsoft account to Outlook - Nope, can't add it as it doesn't have mail associated with it.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more failures where I tried exporting contacts as VCF and importing into my Google account (imported 9 out of 209 - no message to indicate why the remaining 200 didn't import) and trying to import the VCF direct onto the phone (failed completely with a message indicating the format was invalid) I eventually tried the Smart Switch app again, this time it prompted me to update it when I opened it so I did and this time it worked. It took a couple of hours but it seems to have worked ok.